# RAM issue with DASK and its from_pandas function

Tags: python, pandas, ram, dask

i'm trying to use DASK package in Python 3.4 for avoid RAM problems with large datasets, but i've notice a problem.

Using native fucntion "read_csv" i load big dataset into a dask dataframe using less than 150MB of RAM.

The same dataset read with PANDAS DB Connection (using limit and offset options) and dask fuction"from_pandas" fill my ram uo to 500/750 MB.

I can't undestand why this happens and i want to fix this issue.

Here the code:

```
def read_sql(schema,tab,cond):

sql_count="""Select count(*) from """+schema+"""."""+tab
if (len(cond)>0):
    sql_count+=""" where """+cond

a=pd.read_sql_query(sql_count,conn)
num_record=a['count'][0]

volte=num_record//10000
print(num_record)

if(num_record%10000>0):
    volte=volte+1

sql_base="""Select * from """+schema+"""."""+tab
if (len(cond)>0):
    sql_base+=""" where """+cond
sql_base+=""" limit 10000"""

base=pd.read_sql_query(sql_base,conn)

dataDask=dd.from_pandas(base, npartitions=None, chunksize=1000000)

for i in range(1,volte):
    if(i%100==0):
        print(i)
    sql_query="""Select * from """+schema+"""."""+tab
    if (len(cond)>0):
        sql_query+=""" where """+cond
    sql_query+=""" limit 10000 offset """+str(i*10000)

    a=pd.read_sql_query(sql_query,conn)

    b=dd.from_pandas(a , npartitions=None, chunksize=1000000)

    divisions = list(b.divisions)
    b.divisions = (None,)*len(divisions)
    dataDask=dataDask.append(b)

return dataDask



a=read_sql('schema','tabella','data>\'2016-06-20\'')
```

Thanks for help me

Waiting for news

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One dask.dataframe is composed of many pandas dataframes or, as in the case of functions like `read_csv` a plan to compute those dataframes on demand.  It achieves low-memory execution by executing that plan to compute dataframes lazily.

When using `from_pandas` the dataframes are already in memory, so there is little that dask.dataframe can do to avoid memory blowup.

In this case I see three solutions:

- Build a `dask.dataframe.read_sql` function to lazily pull chunks of data from a database.  At the time of writing this is in progress here: https://github.com/dask/dask/pull/1181
- Use `dask.delayed` to achieve the same result in user code.  See http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/delayed.html and http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/delayed-collections.html (this is my main suggestion in your case)
- Dump your database to something like an HDF file, for which there is already a convenient dask.dataframe function.

Comment: Thank you, i will try this methods as soon as possible and then i will give you a response.